# Spark Failed- Futures timed out

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm using apache spark 2.2.1, that running on Amazon EMR cluster. Sometimes jobs fail on 'Futures timed out':

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
>   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
>   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:401)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:254)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:762)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)

I changed 2 params in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout 1000
spark.network.timeout 10000000
```

but it didn't help.

Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this timeout?

Comment: By looking at the trace, this seems not related to `broadcast` hence `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout 1000` may not help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `spark.yarn.am.waitTime`?

> Only used in cluster mode. Time for the YARN Application Master to
>   wait for the SparkContext to be initialized.

The quote above is from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

*A bit more context on my situation:*

I am using spark-submit to execute a java-spark job.  I deploy the client to the cluster, and the client is doing a very long running operation which was causing a time out.

I got around it by:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.yarn.am.waitTime=600000"
```